# how can I set initial viewController that can push after instantiate in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I can't push from initial viewController after using this code

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Identifier)

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: What does it mean? - *I can't push*

Comment: `instantiateViewController` this method doesn't return *initial*, this one does - `instantiateInitialViewController()`

Answer (score 1):

You have to Embed UIViewController in a UINavigationController. Try this one:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Identifier)

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)

self.window?.rootViewController = navController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```